# Manipulating Iframe sizes with Jquery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the size of an iframe with a jQuery link to no avail.
This is the code I used:

```
.right_iframe {
    width: 49%;
}
.right_iframe.active {
    width: 20%;
}

<iframe align="left" width="49%" height="100%" src="page1.html">
</iframe>
<iframe class="right_iframe" align="right" height="100%" src="http://www.msn.com"></iframe>
```

Then this is page1.html

```
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.link").live("click", function(){
       jQuery(".right_iframe").addClass("active");
   });
});
```

[Here's a live example](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/iframes/)

Thanks for your help everyone :)!

Comment: Why not $ instead of jQuery in your code?  Here line 5. Also using document.ready? Would also use .on instead of .live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your jQuery code is running within the context of the first `<iframe>`, it only has access to the DOM for that frame. There's no `.right_iframe` within it, so your code does not sucessfully target anything.

You have to explicitly tell jQuery to look into the DOM of the "parent" document (which contains both frames) to achieve your goal. For example, change your click handler to this:

```
$(window.top.document).find(".right_iframe").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! Also, I needed to load jquery and my functions into the iframe page, not the main index one. Thanks again :)!